# Wordpress, 403 Error not solved by usual methods

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-403

I've encountered a 403 error with the message

> "Forbidden! You don't have permission to access /wp-admin/install.php
>   on this server."

when trying to install a WordPress website for the first time on this server.

I thought it would be quite easy to solve, but after many tries and researches, the error persists.

Here's what I've done so far :

- Allowing all modification on the .htaccess file, using the following code :

```
<files install.php>
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
 </files>
 <files wp-config.php>
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
 </files>
```

and same but with Allow only, or

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

- Changing the permissions : 644 to all files and 755 to all folders, including www.
- Configuring the wp-config.php file manually, by entering the database informations (password, etc.), that I checked by login successfully on phpmyadmin.
- Even setting the wp-admin/install.php to 777

Nothing works. I still have the same error.

I'm running out of options now. The weird thing is that I managed to install wordpress websites on other subdomains but on the same server (same ftp) without any problem. I'm beginning to think that the error comes from the subdomain, since everything worked nice last time.

Thanks a lot for your help ! Do not hesitate to ask anything if you want further details

Comment: One option I didn't see listed on your comments: asking your hosting provider. Have you tried reaching out to them about this?

Comment: That's what I'll do if I can't find a solution. As I said, the error might come from the server itself (more precisely the subdomain), so yeah I'll contact the owner. But I would like to be sure I did not forget any simple solution